# Object that is not in preview is in render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I am new to Blender, and decided to try making a short animation of a metal monkey head exploding.

I wanted to export it as an MP4, so I followed the instructions( going into the render tab, setting it to export as MPEG video with h264 in mp4 encoding), however, when it renders, the MP4 file is complete blackness with a tiny picture of a green and orange checkered cube that undergoes several light changes.

At first, I thought it was because I didn't have enough lighting, as that is what problems like these usually are. However, it is not, because first of all, I added a sun to the project and got the same result, and second of all, the green and orange checkered cube has had visibility turned off. The camera is also facing the monkey object, I made sure of that by setting my perspective to be from the camera's POV.

Why does it appear to be cropping the green and orange cube, and why is it showing that cube in the first place?

A portion of the exploding monkey animation preview

[image: A portion of the exploding monkey animation preview]

Render

[image]
EEVEE Engine

[image]
Cycles Engine

[image]
Let me know if you need more info.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that while visibility is off for workspace, it's not off for renders. There are a lot of objects in the scene that are rendering. Go to the Outliner window, and up in the upper right hand corner you'll see what looks like a funnel. Click on that, and up pops different visibility and selection toggles. You'll see the "render" setting (a little camera) is lit up for all those cubes and planes you have left in the scene.

Blender isn't like photoshop, where if you turn off the visibility of a layer, it's not active. So make sure you click those cameras to turn off what you don't want to see in the render, and see if that works.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I should have updated this more, but throughout the day I have seen the problem evolve, and just solved this. A lot of the problem had to do with render vs. workspace visibility. More of the problem had to do with random project settings, so much so that I had to copy the stuff over to a new project. From there, I really just had to find the show emitter setting in Particle Settings -> Render, and turn that on.